# Editing font size in matplotlib Pie chart within a streamlit app

Tags: python, matplotlib, streamlit

In the code below the pie chart displays a bold normal value on top of a corresponding percent value in each slice of the pie using the autopct_format function. I want to know if there is a way to edit the font size of the pct value to make it smaller while leaving the normal value at its current font-size. Streamlit blocks many solutions so please let me know if you find a way to solve this?

I've tried using span within the return but streamlit doesn't allow that, and I tried setting textprop sizes but that sets the size for the entire slice(both pct and val)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st

# Data
sizes = [6, 5, 10]
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# Function to display both percentage and value
def autopct_format(pct):
    total = sum(sizes)
    val = int(round(pct/100.0 * total))
    return '$\mathbf{{ {:d} }}$ \n {:.1f}%'.format(val, pct)

# Plotting
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax2.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct=lambda pct: autopct_format(pct), textprops={'fontsize': 24})


# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
ax2.axis('equal')

st.pyplot(fig2)
```